# Make: how to figure the path to make.exe?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Latest update: the issue only happens when $(MAKE) is used in make includes. In the top-level makefile it works regardless of the path.

The issue affects both Cygwin and MSYS2.

If the folder containing make.exe is not added to the default path, the user can still start my build system by specifying the path to make. (e.g., c:\msys64\usr\bin\make)
In the top-level makefile, make can be restarted through $(MAKE), or coreutils can be invoked through $(dir $(MAKE))/touch, for example.
However, this does not work in make includes! If the top-level makefile includes another .mak file, in that file $(MAKE) does not work anymore.
If the folder of make is added to the default path, it works.
Any idea how to make it working?

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the specific GNU `make` port you are using; probably report it to them (apparently Cygwin / MSYS2?)

Comment: "The user might start make with its absolute path" is malpractice in my book. I'd allow you to simply not support that. Plenty other tools work the same way. The environment must be managed. Absolute paths cancel any hope for management.

Comment: Yes the behavior is the same for Cygwin and MSYS2. Might be a bug, will report and check. GnuWin32 does not come with bash, EZWinPorts lacks most coreutils, any other idea? Absolute path could be a solution, assuming that all coreutils are in the same folder as make. Figure the folder from $(MAKE) and invoke all tools through that path. Works if the bin folder is moved from its default location, fails when using the default installation location. Thanks guys! Let me know if you have any further information.

Comment: Turned out that what matters is how was make invoked through absolute or relative path. Still a bug I guess. Also bad practice but would be convenient for my users.